# Prestashop website error. Website showing fatal error mb_convert_encoding

Tags: prestashop, mb-convert-encoding

I have a prestashop website http://www.mumsnbabysupermart.com.au/. The website was fully functional BUT suddenly website stop working and shows a fatal error. The error is-

```
Fatal error : call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding() in home/xxx/xxx/public_html/cache/smarty/comile/94/23/30/942330f3aff64545a59bff57a8a2078fb44cd308.file.heeader.tpl.php on line 78.
```

I did googling but found nothing. In this website i integrated Australia Post, eWay and Paypal.

Comment: What version of PHP do you use ? In a `phpinfo()` page, what does the `mbstring` section shows ?

Comment: Core

PHP Version  - 5.3.29

Comment: clear your cache and see if that magically helps.   "cache/smarty/compile" is certainly an indication that it is a cached  file giving you a problem.  Of course, that doesn't mean clearing it will fix it if it is the file being cached that has the problem too.   Unlikely to fix, but give it a try anyway.

Comment: @KapilSinghal Did it work for you? You can try to do it manually as I've mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have mb_string enabled on your server?

If not, you'll need to contact your service provider and ask they to enable it.

Think about debug mode, too:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Performance+Parameters
You may disable non Prestashop modules and overrides.

If you still receive this error, use "Force compilation" in Smarty and disable cache.

Did you update PrestaShop recently?

Comment: Yes i have mb_string enable on my serve.

no i didn't update my Prestashop.

Comment: Did you disable every cache option? Please enable dev mode: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/PrestaShop's+developer+tools "On your server, open the /config/defines.inc.php file.
Find this line: define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
In this line, change "false" to "true".
Save your changes."

Comment: You can try to manually delete cache files in "smarty/compile".